# Translate success message for newsletter signup

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, localisation, newsletter

I want to translate the success message for my newsletter signup. So in the `Mage_Newsletter.csv` I have added

```
"Thank you for your subscription.","Tak for din tilmelding"
```

But it's not getting translated, what am I missing?

Comment: try with exact word including space as well and don't forget to clear the cache

Comment: just tried again nothing new. Ive done this meny times, but now its not working.

Comment: try this "Thank you for your subscription.","Tak for din tilmelding" and also clear cache in admin side.

Comment: good idea, but no :(

Comment: try to add it in your theme local folder for ex.
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/locale/your_Locale/translate.csv

Comment: great idea. but no luck. I just tried to catch it with the inline translate tool. and the scope is from the module DigitalPianism_CampaignMonitor can it be it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the file where you are displaying the message -

```
echo $this->__('Thank you for your subscription.');
```

I hope you have not missed this.

Comment: I have tried, but no luck :( I ended up inline translate it all. Not optimal.